# Problems Retrieving JWT from AsyncStorage to Create httpLink Middleware with ApolloClient

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, graphql, asyncstorage

I'm pretty much copy/pasting the example code from the [Apollo GraphQL Network Layer Docs on Creating Middleware](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/network-layer.html#linkMiddleware), except I'm pulling my dependencies from `apollo-client-preset` and I'm using a simple utility library to return the jwt token. Here's the link code...

```
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache, ApolloLink, concat } from 'apollo-client-preset';
import { getSessionToken } from './api/localStorage';

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: 'http://localhost:4000/' });

const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  const token = getSessionToken();
  const authorizationHeader = token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null;

  operation.setContext({
    headers: {
      authorization: authorizationHeader,
    }
  });

  return forward(operation);
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: concat(authMiddleware, httpLink),
});
```

And here's the `./api/localStorage` method in play...

```
export const getSessionToken = () => {
    return AsyncStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN);
}
```

Executing the above code results in an HTTP request with the following headers...

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4000
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: Expo/2.2.0.1011489 CFNetwork/893.14 Darwin/17.3.0
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Authorization: Bearer [object Object]
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 174
```

> Notice the `Authorization: Bearer [object Object]` bit

I think the problem is pretty obvious. AsyncStorage is an async function, and I need to wait for the promise to be resolved before I assemble the authorization string. The solution, however, is less obvious. I've tried various methods, but no love so far.

I've seen a couple examples similar to the above. Here's another in the [How to GraphQL Authentication Module](https://www.howtographql.com/react-apollo/5-authentication/). Neither shows how to wait for the asyncstorage promise to resolve first. I know Apollo waits for the promises for you automagically sometimes, so I thought that might be the case here. But doesn't seem to be in my experience.

So what's the solution?

## Here's a couple things I've tried, but that have failed.

### 1. Promise.then()

```
const middlewareAuthLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  getSessionToken().then(token => {
    const authorizationHeader = token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null
    operation.setContext({
      headers: {
        authorization: authorizationHeader
      }
    })
  });

  return forward(operation)
})
```

This does construct the authorization string properly, but doesn't seem to create the middleware because this does not create the authorization header. To me, this seems like my best bet, but I must be doing it wrong for reasons which are not obvious to me.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4000
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Expo/2.2.0.1011489 CFNetwork/893.14 Darwin/17.3.0
Content-Length: 174
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

> Notice the lack of `Authorization` header

### 2. async/await

I thought this would be pretty straight forward, turning this into an async/await function, but not so much. Here's the code

```
const middlewareAuthLink = new ApolloLink(async (operation, forward) => {
  const token = await getSessionToken();
  const authorizationHeader = token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null;

  operation.setContext({
    headers: {
      authorization: authorizationHeader,
    }
  });
  return forward(operation)
})
```

But that resulted in this super ugly red-screen-of-death error...

```
Unhandled (in react-apollo:Apollo(EventList)), ApolloError@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:106405:36
currentResult@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:106516:43
dataForChild@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:101608:79
render@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:101659:49
finishClassComponent@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:4528:102
performUnitOfWork@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:5547:33
workLoop@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:5566:142
_invokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:2707:23
invokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:2681:41
performWork@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:5602:41
scheduleUpdateImpl@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:5723:105
enqueueForceUpdate@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:4341:179
forceUpdate@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:8265:38
forceRenderChildren@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:101579:58
next@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:101554:50
error@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:109797:25
forEach@[native code]
error@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:106747:44
http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:107277:47
http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:107649:29
forEach@[native code]
http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:107648:27
forEach@[native code]
broadcastQueries@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:107644:33
http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:107239:51
tryCallOne@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:10901:14
http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:10987:25
_callTimer@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:12157:15
_callImmediatesPass@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:12193:17
callImmediates@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:12397:31
__callImmediates@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:2301:30
http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:2179:32
__guard@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:2287:11
flushedQueue@http://localhost:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=/Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/exp/frogquest-app/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles:2178:19
flushedQueue@[native code]
invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
```

### So how do I wait for the result of AsyncStorage to return before setting the header?

Comment: your first "attempt" ... `return forward(operation)` is executed before the `.then(token => {` code is executed, because of asynchronism

Comment: You're right, but moving the return inside the then() doesn't achieve the desires result either

Comment: well, know, because asynchronism can't be defeated !

Comment: You lost me, but do you know where I've gone wrong? I feel like I should know the answer, but not so far

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There may be other solutions, or better solutions even, but this finally worked for me so I'm posting it as solved.

```
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: 'http://localhost:4000/'});

const authHeader = setContext(
  request =>
    new Promise((success, fail) => {
      getSessionToken().then(token => success({ headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }}))
    })
)

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: concat(authHeader, httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})
```

Comment: Won't this run on every single request?

Comment: @david_adler yes, thankfully. JWT is stateless, so having the auth header attached to each requests is what you want.

Comment: Yes but do you really want to fetch from `AsyncStorage` every time you make a request. Probably will add some milliseconds to every request

Comment: Educate me. Show me a better way if you know of any

Comment: What is the function `getSessionToken()`?

Comment: Also it looks like setContext no longer exists in the latest Apollo codebase

Comment: @Ben the function `getSessionToken()` is referenced with more context in the original question. It basically just retrieves the token from local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative which loads the token from an in memory cache which should perform better than fetching from `AsyncStorage`. Alternatively you could simply have a getter wrapper function which caches the response from `AsyncStorage` but having this as part of apollo cache has the added benefit of re-rendering when you update the token.

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client'
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context'
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'

const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  const context = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query AuthQuery {
        authToken @client
      }
    `
  })
  const {
    data: { authToken: token }
  } = context
  let extra = {}
  if (token) {
    extra = { authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
  }
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      ...extra
    }
  }
})

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/'
})

const cache = new InMemoryCache()

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([authLink, httpLink]),
  cache
})

client.writeData({ data: { authToken: null } })

AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((token: string | null) => {
  if (token) {
    client.writeData({ data: { authToken: token } })
  }
})

export { client }
```